# Showing and Hiding a table from link click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to set up table that starts off hidden when the page loads but will appear when the down arrow `tarrow` next to the heading is clicked. I've tried moving some stuff around in the CSS but it was no use. The JavaScript console displays this `<div class="content .showTable">...</div>` When I load the page

```js
let tarrow = document.querySelectorAll(".tarrow");
for (var i = 0; i < tarrow.length; i++) {
  tarrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    let tarrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    console.log(tarrowParent);
    tarrowParent.classList.toggle(".showTable");
  });
}
```

```css
.content{
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding: 15px;

}

.bantable{
     border-collapse: collapse;
     
  }
  .bantable .table-display i.tarrow{
     border-collapse: collapse;
     
  }


  .bantable td{
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccd9df;
  }
  .bantable th{
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccd9df;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccd9df;
  }
  .bantable tr:hover {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
  }
  .bantable a{
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
  }

  .bantable i{

  }

  .table-heading{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    
  }

  .table-heading i{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .content .bantable {
    display: none;
  }

  .content .showtable {
    display: block;
  }

  .bantable .sub-table li.goog i.tarrow{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  .table-heading:hover i{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .table-heading a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #757272;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="table-heading">
<a href="#">Active Temp Bans & Infractions</a><i class="bx bxs-chevron-down tarrow"></i></div>
<table class="bantable" width="100%">
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>IP Address</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Reason</th>
<th>Created</th>
<th>ACP</th>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>Test Name</td>
<td></td>
<td>0.0.0.0</td>
<td>Suspension 2 Weeks</td>
<td>Details<td>2016-01-04 19:17:00</td>
<td>Edit</td>
<tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I overlooked several things. Check out this snippet.

The .tarrow element wasn't clickable, because it had no width or height. I added a + symbol, so that I could click it.

In the CSS, I updated/added:

```
    .content.showTable .bantable {
        display: block;
    }
```

In the JS, you only had to remove the . from the toggle function class name, but I made some overall changes.

```js
const tarrow = document.querySelectorAll(".tarrow");
        for (var i = 0; i < tarrow.length; i++) {
            tarrow[i].onclick = function(e){
                toggleTable(e)
            }
        }
        
        function toggleTable(e){
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("showTable");
        }
```

```css
.content{
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding: 15px;

}

.bantable{
     border-collapse: collapse;
     
  }
  .bantable .table-display i.tarrow{
     border-collapse: collapse;
     
  }


  .bantable td{
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccd9df;
  }
  .bantable th{
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccd9df;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccd9df;
  }
  .bantable tr:hover {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
  }
  .bantable a{
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
  }

  .bantable i{

  }

  .table-heading{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    
  }

  .table-heading i{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }
  .content .bantable {
    display: none;
  }

  .content.showTable .bantable {
    display: block;
  }

  .bantable .sub-table li.goog i.tarrow{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  .table-heading:hover i{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 78px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .table-heading a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #757272;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="table-heading">

<a href="#">Active Temp Bans & Infractions</a><i class="bx bxs-chevron-down tarrow">+</i></div>

<table class="bantable" width="100%">
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>IP Address</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Reason</th>
<th>Created</th>
<th>ACP</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Test Name</td>
<td></td>
<td>0.0.0.0</td>
<td>Suspension 2 Weeks</td>
<td>Details<td>2016-01-04 19:17:00</td>
<td>Edit</td>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work now the console shows <div class="content">...</div>
When the down arrow is clicked it show <div class="content showTable">...</div>

Comment: Sorry, about that. Check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your js function to this.

```
function click() {
let tarrow = document.querySelectorAll(".tarrow");
        for (var i = 0; i < tarrow.length; i++) {
            tarrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
            const table = document.querySelector(".bantable");
            table.classList.toggle("showtable");
            });
       }
}
```

and you had a typo in `table.classList.toggle("showtable");` line, in your CSS the class name is `showtable`, you added the class name in JS as '.showTable'. and you don't need the `.` in front of the class name when you add it to toggle function also.